# How to strip single quote from a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to strip a single quote from a  tag because it's conflicting with some javascript functionality on the page. What's the best method for me to do this?

```
<span class="field-content" data-live-anchor="jes's-mon">Group A</span>
```

Comment: you can split the value using `'` then combine them again

Comment: A simpler method: use `encodeURIComponent()`. Then when retrieving, use `decodeURIComponent()`. This is the principle of url encoding

Comment: May be worth investigating if this "javascript functionality" cannot be fixed.

Comment: Can you give more details about what it's conflicting with. It should not cause any issue in your JS code

Comment: `$(".field-content").data("live-anchor").replace("'","")`

Comment: Classic XY problem - what's the *actual* problem that the apostrophe causes?

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <span class="field-content" data-live-anchor="jes's-mon">Group A</span>
       <script>
          var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("field-content")[0];
           str = ele.getAttribute("data-live-anchor");
           var newStr = str.replace(/\'/gmi,'');
           alert(newStr);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP may need this single quote for further processing. It has to be saved. So you cannot directly remove it.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy this, so much this.  Hi, what's your name:  "Mr O'Conner", welcome to our app "Mr OConner"... really?